# Moving between steps in numbered list in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Is there a key binding for org-mode to move between numbered/bulleted list items as you can do with headings?

Like the functions:

1. org-forward-heading-same-level
2. outline-next-visible-heading

Answer (score 3):

You can use `org-next-item` or `org-forward-element`

> (org-next-item)
>
> Move to the beginning of the next item. Throw an error when not in a
>   list.  Also throw an error when at last item, unless
>   `org-list-use-circular-motion' is non-nil.

Org-forward element will also move to the next paragraph/heading/table if that follows.

> (org-forward-element)
>
> Move forward by one element. Move to the next element at the same
>   level, when possible.